# How to get a compile time failure when calling a method on self.class in objective-c that is actually not a class methods?

Tags: objective-c

Assume the following code in objective-c

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation TestClass

- (void)doSomething {}

- (void)iWillCrash
{
    [self.class doSomething];
}

+ (void)iWillNotCompile
{
    [self doSomething];
}
@end
```

My issue is that until now I often use `self.class` to call a class method from a non class method in the same class. Today I found out that I do not get any compile time error if the method (in the example `doSomething`) is actually not a class method as in the example above. But this will obviously crash during runtime.
To make this worse, I will not even get an error if `doSomething` is not even a valid method in my own class, but in any other class that is included in my class file.

I can of course solve this issue by using `[TestClass doSomething]`

But I find this redundant and not intuitive.

I tried something like `[__typeof(self) doSomething]`
But that does not work.

Is there a better way to get compile time errors without having to duplicate the name of my class in my source file every time I call a class method from within a method of same class?

By the way `iWillNotCompile` will fail as expected.

I'm using Xcode 11.3

TL-DR: I do not want to know hot to get `iWillNotCompile` to compile, but how to get `iWillCrash` to not compile without explicitly use class name in call.

Comment: There is no such error/warning, because it is intentional feature. It gives possibility to subclass `TestClass`, say `DoingSomethingTestClass` and implement in it `+doSomething` method, so its instances could call `-iWillCrash` not crashing. In such cases it is usually said that `TestClass` is semi-abstract class. Also class-clusters often use this feature.

Comment: What should happen in child classes? If you use `[TestClass doSomething]`, child classes will not be able to override it.

Comment: You can use C-functions instead of class methods.